# Is is possible to write a Spring Data JPA query method name with logical operator grouping?

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data

Let's say I have an entity class like this (minimal code for brevity):

```java
@Entity
public class Thing {
    private Long groupID;
    private String name;
    private String description;
}
```

Requirement is to implement a search for a String value present in either `name` or `description`, for `Thing`s with a specific `groupID`. I'd try writing a Spring Data JPA "derived" query method like one of these:

```java
public ThingRepo extends JpaRepository<Thing, Long> {

    public Collection<Thing> findByGroupIDAndNameContainsOrDescriptionContains(Long groupID, String name, String description);

    public Collection<Thing> findByNameContainsOrDescriptionContainsAndGroupID(String name, String description, Long groupID);
}
```

To search for the same text in either `name` or `description`, I'd pass that same value for both method arguments. However, neither of these produces the expected results, because of how Spring Data processes the logical `And` and `Or` operators in the method name - I can't find any way to group the `name` and `description` criteria with logical `Or`.

Is there a way to implement a query method like this without resorting to JPQL and `@Query`?

Comment: I also need to ignore case in the query, but I left that out to keep the example simple. The method name would include `AllIgnoreCase` to do that.

Comment: I do understand that the method name gets pretty verbose and awkward at this point, but I'm curious how to do this kind of thing anyway, even if I eventually choose to not use a "method name derived" query.

Comment: The precedence order is `And` then `Or`, just like Java. You might have to do something along the lines of name and groupid OR description and groupid -> (either name and group id matches or description and group id matches)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`findByGroupIDAndNameContainsOrDescriptionContains(...)` evaluates to `(A∧B)∨C` but if I understood correctly you want
`A∧(B∨C)` which is equivalent to `(A∧B)∨(A∧C)`, so it should be

```
public Collection<Thing> findByGroupIdAndNameContainsOrGroupIdAndDescriptionContains(Long groupId1, String name, Long groupId2, String description)
```

where `name=description` and `groupId1=groupId2`.

Answer (score 0):

The precedence order is And then Or, just like Java. You might have to do something along the lines of `name` and `groupid` OR `description` and `groupid` which means either name and group id matches or description and group id matches.

so, your method could be named:

```java
public ThingRepo extends JpaRepository<Thing, Long> {
    public Collection<Thing> 
       findByGroupIDAndNameContainsOrGroupIDAndDescriptionContains
           (Long groupId, String name, Long groupId2, String description);
}
```